# Am I screwed? Transferred USDT from Polinex to USD dollars in Coinbase and now it's gone

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info, lost-transactions

I've seen others post where they transferred their USDT to a bitcoin address and it got lost.  I specifically clicked on my USD instead of BTC and it provided me with an address to send it to.  However, the same thing happened where it says it's pending and only .0000273 getting transferred.  I transferred a decent chunk of change.

So here's where it's interesting, if I going to omnichannel and type in the address where the USDT was sent, it shows the full amount still available.  I know it's there and the omni wallet shows it but it doesn't let me get access to it.  If I try to import a private key and add an address on to my omniwallet, it let's me put in the TXID associated with the transaction but pulls up zero as the balance.

Any ideas or options out there?  I know the amount is still out there but I can't seem to get it.  I've heard something about importing private keys but I don't know how to find it.  Or am I just plain ole screwed and will have to learn my lesson.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That happened to me too. Support took weeks to get back to me and basically said "too bad". Did you find a solution?

Comment: No luck.  I can still see the USDT available when I look it up through the blockchain but i can't get it.   At this point, i would offer have of the available funds to anyone who can get it.   Basically $1k up for grabs.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have access to your Private keys on coinbase, as it is considered a custodial wallet, which means only they have access to it. I highly doubt they would give you these private keys as its not standard practice. You only option is to email support. I doubt they would care. Another option is to ask someone inside coinbase to help you, but you'll need connections to do that I imagine.